# Send request to plugin and get result in C#

Tags: c#, plugins, console-application

I have software that takes your request, And I want to control requests with the plugins.
Fore example console writes: `Enter Request:` and i write `time`
well, Now I want the software to check if any plugin supports this command and then turn back the time and more (day, mouth, list of plugins, ...).

> I looked at other sources but could not implement the project.
> I hope someone can help me. :) Thanks.

Comment: Optionally, give the link to download the source of the created project, because I will learn better in practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can adapt this MS tutorial and get what you want.

https://docs.miosoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support

It shows how to load pluggins and execute. From what you are describing this is what you are looking.